# JQuery ajax stoppen in $.when when server returns 500 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .when

I make a request to a server with JQuery and the $.when method.

```
  $.when(ajaxRequest(param)).done(function(response){
    console.log(responseData);
  });
```

my ajax function looks like this:

```
function ajaxRequest(param){
  var requestedData;
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: myurl,
    data: {
        setParam:param
    },
    error: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      return(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Everything works fine if the server returns a 200 OK. But if there was something wrong the server answers with 500. How can I return the response body to the calling method?

The errorbody is printed with console.log on the ajaxRequest method but its not returned to the calling method?

Comment: Add a `.fail()` handler after `.done()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for the hint! Worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `js` at Question `$.when()` is not necessary as `$.ajax()` returns a jQuery promise object. `var requestedData;` is not set to a value, would be `undefined` at `.done()`; use `response` available at `.then()` or `.done()` as returned data;  [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then) to handle both success and error responses

```
function ajaxRequest(param){
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: myurl,
    data: {
      setParam:param
    }
  });
}

ajaxRequest(param)
.then(function(response){
  console.log(response);
  return response
}
// handle errors at second function of `.then()`
, function err(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
  return errorThrown;
});
```